# Adding alt tag inside PHP image element

Tags: tags, alt

I have this code:

```
<?php } else { ?>

<div class="bgft"><img src="<?php echo CinemaFlix_Directory. 'public/img/poster.webp'; ?>"> </div>

<?php }
```

How to add `alt` tag in this code? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to add the alt attribute for the img tag ? is that it ? if so you can simply write alt in the img tag like this : <img alt="..." src="..." />